# Calling Looper.prepare() in a thread's constructor results in RunTimeException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-thread

I have a `class` which extends to `Thread` as follows -

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread {

    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    public ThreadTest(Runnable runnable, Handler handler) {

        this.handler = handler;
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.obj = "YUSSSSSS!";
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

        if (Looper.myLooper() != null) {
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
            Log.i("Looper", "has been quit");
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I wish to attach a `looper` to this thread. From my understanding of `Looper` only the main thread gets a `looper` attached to it by default.

I try to call `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` form the constructor of the `ThreadTest` class like this -

```
public ThreadTest(Runnable runnable, Handler handler) {

        Looper.prepare();

        this.handler = handler;
        this.runnable = runnable;

        Looper.loop();
    }
```

But, I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread` exception at `Looper.prepare();`.

While, if I attach the `looper` in `Run()`, I don't face any problem whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @pskink Where? When I call `Looper.prepare()` on the constructor, I don't call it under `run()`.

Comment: @pskink I'm just playing around with multi tasking in Android. I never call prepare() twice. Hence, this question.

Comment: this is because you are calling `Looper#prepare` on the main UI thread (inside `ThreadTest` constructor), it already has `Looper` atached

Comment: @pskink Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Every thread has a looper and only have one looper, you need to make a check before you are trying to add a looper to a thread.

You need to add  `if (Looper.myLooper() != null) {}` in your constructor too.
And remember the `looper.myLooper()`  can only get Main thread Looper if you call it in the thread constructor. Because at that time the new thread has not constructed yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Looper.prepare()` in the constructor, it's actually being called from whatever other thread that's creating the object by calling its constructor (you didn't specify but I'm guessing the main thread) but the `run()` method is called from the thread itself. So you should attach your `looper` in `run()`.

And for `run()` to be called, you have to call `Thread.start()` and there's no guaranty that `run()` will be called immediately after you call `start()` so if you want the `looper` to be available immediately after calling the constructor, you can wait in the constructor until `run()` is called and then `notify()` the waiting thread in the constructor like this:

```java
public class ThreadTest extends Thread
{
    public ThreadTest()
    {
        //init...

        //wait until thread has started
        waitForRun();
    }

    private void waitForRun()
    {
        try
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                start();
                wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored)
        {
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        synchronized (this)
        {
            //notify the waiting thread in the constructor that this thread
            //has started and has a looper
            notifyAll();
        }

        //do stuff...

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```